# How to block downloads in .NET WebBrowser control?

Tags: .net, browser, download

I need to prevent the .NET WebBrowser control from showing any "Do you want to open or save this file?" and "Save As" dialogs. Instead, I want to display a message box telling users that file downloads are disabled for security reasons.

I started with the `FileDownload` event of `WebBrowser`, but it does not allow cancellation. Then, I used the approach from [CodeProject: Extended .NET 2.0 WebBrowser Control](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cpp/ExtendedWebBrowser.aspx?fid=285594&select=2560552) to implement my own event based on the original COM call using the interface `DWebBrowserEvents2`. When I fixed the code according to [an MS knowledge base entry about a bug with the FileDownload signature](http://support.microsoft.com/?scid=kb%3Ben-us%3B325204&x=15&y=12), the event handler was called and I was able to cancel the download.

This does not work with all downloads, though: download URLs pointing to an URL including `.exe` raise the event and can be cancelled before the dialog appears - but for others (like `.do`), the event handler is not called until the user clicks `Open`, `Save` or `Cancel` in the dialog.

A possible solution might be to [intercept `WH_CALLWNDPROCRET` messages and 'answer' the dialog before it is shown to the user](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/shell/WebBrowserControlDialogs.aspx), but it sounds like much effort and I also would prefer a cleaner solution...

Does anybody know how to reliably block all downloads?

Comment: Let me get this strait... You want to allow internet access for your users (which is nothing more than downloading files into the computer) and you want to block ALL downloads?

Comment: @Sergio: I think, Jens want block all files, which can not be displayed directly in webbrowser.

Comment: TcKs is right, I want to block everything that can't be displayed. The point is not to prevent downloads, but to prevent any "Save file as" dialogs from showing so that the user has no way of accessing the hard disk. My application is installed as the windows shell (no Explorer, no start menu).

Answer (score 3):

You could use `Navigating` event which allows cancellation.

Inside of this event, you could try to connect to URL that's being navigated yourself, inspect http response headers and cancel navigating if inappropriate ContentType is detected.

```
System.Net.WebRequest request = System.Net.WebRequest.Create(e.Url);

// we need only header part of http response
request.Method = "HEAD";

System.Net.WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();

// only text/html, text/xml, text/plain are allowed... extend as required
if (!response.ContentType.StartsWith("text/"))
{
  e.Cancel = true;
  MessageBox.Show("Not allowed for security resons...");
}
```

Obviously this is not bullet-proof solution but can give you an idea how to get started (if you don't mind extra tiny roundtrip just to retrieve http response headers).

> **Jens Bannmann wrote:**
>
> This is not ideal, as I'm dealing with
>   web applications where the extra
>   request might trigger an action being
>   carried out twice :-(

Then I would create some simple proxy server that would inspect all received data and would filter out all http responses that could trigger "Save as" dialog in your web-browser control.

Simply, don't let your web-browser control directly access the internet but delegate all http requests to your special proxy server that will filter out all unsafe responses from the web.

Comment: Hmm, hooking up a proxy instead of somehow blocking/disabling the dialog doesn't strike me as an elegant solution.

Anyway, could I add a proxy without installing additional software, i.e. only using the .NET framework?

Comment: I think it's quite elegant solution and makes sense. Also your code will not suddenly break with future versions of IE. You can implement simple proxy server within your own software. If you don't know how to do it, post another question, you will get more answers.

Comment: a proxy won't work reliably as it won't be able to see the url or headers for https connections.

Answer (score 3):

The only reliable way seems to be to hook into the Windows event queue and suppress the dialog boxes (as all sorts of things can get the user access). This is what our helper class does:

```
    void ListenForDialogCreation()
    {
        // Listen for name change changes across all processes/threads on current desktop...
        _WinEventHook = WinAPI.SetWinEventHook(WinAPI.EVENT_OBJECT_CREATE, procDelegate);
    }
    void StopListeningForDialogCreation()
    {
        WinAPI.UnhookWinEvent(_WinEventHook);
    }

    void WinEventProc(IntPtr hWinEventHook, uint eventType, IntPtr hwnd, int idObject, int idChild, uint dwEventThread, uint dwmsEventTime)
    {
        const uint OBJID_WINDOW = 0;
        const uint CHILDID_SELF = 0;

        // filter out non-HWND, and things not children of the current application
        if (idObject != OBJID_WINDOW || idChild != CHILDID_SELF)
            return;

        //Get the window class name
        StringBuilder ClassName = new StringBuilder(100);
        WinAPI.GetClassName(hwnd, ClassName, ClassName.Capacity);

        // Send close message to any dialog
        if (ClassName.ToString() == "#32770")
        {
            WinAPI.SendMessage(hwnd, WinAPI.WM.CLOSE, IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero);
            if (OnDialogCancelled != null)
                OnDialogCancelled();
        }
        if (ClassName.ToString() == "#32768")
        {
            WinAPI.SendMessage(hwnd, WinAPI.WM.CLOSE, IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero);
            if (OnDialogCancelled != null)
                OnDialogCancelled();
        }

    }

    public delegate void OnDialogCancelledEvent();
    public event OnDialogCancelledEvent OnDialogCancelled;
```

- #32770 is the Dialog class
- #32768 is the pop-up menu
- the WinAPI namespace is our pinvoke wrappers.

If you don't want to block all Dialogs you'll want to add in some additional filters once you've caught the class. It depends how secure you need to be. At $WORK we needed to block all uploads and downloads.

Suppressing the pop-up menu is necessary as it gives access to the Help application, which gives links to microsoft's website, which enables a full instance of IE to be launched. Then they can do whatever they want.

Comment: Well, this post could help if you've added WinAPI class code. =(

Comment: It's been a while, but I think we just used pinvoke.net to create the wrappers for what we needed.

Answer (score 0):

This project - http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/157329/Http-Monitor-for-Webbrowser-Control allows intercepting and inspecting HTTP traffic from WebBrowser control.

Then you can filter data by MIME and allow only html, images, scripts etc.