# How to parse a raw HTTP response as HttpListenerResponse?

Tags: c#, proxy, httpresponse, socks, httplistener

If I have a raw HTTP response as a string:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK  
Date: Tue, 11 May 2010 07:28:30 GMT  
Expires: -1  
Cache-Control: private, max-age=0  
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8  
Server: gws  
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block  
Connection: close

<!doctype html><html>...</html>
```

Is there an easy way I can parse it into an `HttpListenerResponse` object? Or at least some kind .NET object so I don't have to work with raw responses.

What I'm doing currently is extracting the header key/value pairs and setting them on the `HttpListenerResponse`. But some headers can't be set, and then I have to cut out the body of the response and write it to the `OutputStream`. But the body could be gzipped, or it could be an image, which I can't get to work yet. And some responses contain random characters everywhere, which looks like an encoding problem. It's a lot of trouble.

I'm getting a raw response because I'm using SOCKS to send an HTTP request. The program I'm working on is basically an HTTP proxy that can route requests through a SOCKS proxy, like Privoxy does.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like there's no easy way to convert them. These articles helped:

[How to implement custom proxy server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/506718/how-to-implement-custom-proxy-server)

http://www.jeffcrossman.com/2009/08/27/using-httplistener-to-build-a-proxy

I ended up doing something very similar.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you want to take a look at the [ResponseHeaders](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.responseheaders.aspx) property of the `Webclient`:

```
WebClient wc = new WebClient();
wc.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri("http://www.foo.com"));

WebHeaderCollection myWebHeaderCollection = myWebClient.ResponseHeaders;

for (int i=0; i < myWebHeaderCollection.Count; i++)             
    Console.WriteLine ("\t" + myWebHeaderCollection.GetKey(i) + 
                       " = " + myWebHeaderCollection.Get(i));
```

Please tell me if that isnt what you were searching for.

Comment: Hmm just reread your question, and I think that may not help you if you just get a raw response and have to build up your response by hand...

Comment: Yeah, I'm currently using HttpListenerResponse.Headers.Set(key, value), which is the same thing. But thanks for your reply.