# Dotnet-core convert raw bytes of http-request to HttpRequest class

Tags: c#, .net-core

Let's imagine I have a custom protocol to transport data now I want to wrap an HTTP request in it and pass it to the server on the server I receive a raw byte array of my HTTP request now I want to parse it to `HttpRequest` class.
Is there any way to parse the raw byte array to `HttpRequest` in .net-core? Something like this:

```
Stream mystream = myCustomProtocol.BodyStream; //the body-stream is a complete http request
HttpRequest request = HttpRequestHelper.ReadFrom(mystream);
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/2808866/11683?

Comment: @GSerg 1 link doesn't work and other answer is not work here they just create a proxy i couldn't find any solution to convert raw http string into a class

Comment: @GSerg Look `req, err := http.ReadRequest(c.conn.(*net2.BufferedConn).BufioReader())` this is a sample from golang, i need something similar in .net-core

Comment: Create request like this: `var httpRequest = HttpWebRequest.Create("uri");` Get request stream: `var stream = httpRequest.GetRequestStream();` Read or write to request stream: `stream.Read(...)` or `stream.Write(...)`

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov There isn't a URI, there is already a Stream that contains what would have otherwise been sent as an HTTP response. That is why the duplicate link tells you to set up a proxy server and send that to it, so that at its side it finally can be read with `GetRequestStream` or the sort.

Comment: @GSerg Proxy won't work because the packets wrapped in our custom protocol over tcp-socket. On the server I unwrap http packet and now I gonna process it and I just need parse it to a C# class. Of course I can write my own http parser but I prefer use existing one if there is any

Comment: @AliZeinali You receive the data according to your protocol, then you send the payload as if it was a complete HTTP response via another socket to the proxy.

Comment: @GSerg I don't wanna proxy it, I just wanna parse it to a manageable C# class then process it.