# C# - How to surpress file download dialogs in the webbrowser control?

Tags: c#, .net, browser

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to block downloads in .NET WebBrowser control?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/483262/how-to-block-downloads-in-net-webbrowser-control)

Not much more to add, how do I go about this? Thansk for your help!

Comment: This is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/483262/how-to-block-downloads-in-net-webbrowser-control

Answer (score 2):

You could subscribe to the [`Navigating`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.navigating.aspx) event and do the download in the host application (rather than letting the browser control do it itself).