# C# webbrowser close save file dialog

Tags: c#, dialog, download

I need to disable "save as" file download dialog in webbrowser.

I found this way:

```
void ListenForDialogCreation()
{
    // Listen for name change changes across all processes/threads on current desktop...
    _WinEventHook = WinAPI.SetWinEventHook(WinAPI.EVENT_OBJECT_CREATE, procDelegate);
}
void StopListeningForDialogCreation()
{
    WinAPI.UnhookWinEvent(_WinEventHook);
}

void WinEventProc(IntPtr hWinEventHook, uint eventType, IntPtr hwnd, int idObject, int idChild, uint dwEventThread, uint dwmsEventTime)
{
    const uint OBJID_WINDOW = 0;
    const uint CHILDID_SELF = 0;

    // filter out non-HWND, and things not children of the current application
    if (idObject != OBJID_WINDOW || idChild != CHILDID_SELF)
        return;

    //Get the window class name
    StringBuilder ClassName = new StringBuilder(100);
    WinAPI.GetClassName(hwnd, ClassName, ClassName.Capacity);

    // Send close message to any dialog
    if (ClassName.ToString() == "#32770")
    {
        WinAPI.SendMessage(hwnd, WinAPI.WM.CLOSE, IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero);
        if (OnDialogCancelled != null)
            OnDialogCancelled();
    }
    if (ClassName.ToString() == "#32768")
    {
        WinAPI.SendMessage(hwnd, WinAPI.WM.CLOSE, IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero);
        if (OnDialogCancelled != null)
            OnDialogCancelled();
    }

}

public delegate void OnDialogCancelledEvent();
public event OnDialogCancelledEvent OnDialogCancelled;
```

But here using missing dll. Help me please.

This is where I found the code: [How to block downloads in .NET WebBrowser control?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/483262/how-to-block-downloads-in-net-webbrowser-control)

Comment: I need to disable window with download file...

Comment: You don't need ActiveX for an embedded browser component (System.Controls.Browser, etc) in an existing .net application.

Answer (score 0):

The only thing missing is the pinvoke wrappers, which you can either write yourself from the documentation (or use pinvoke.net for easy reference with cut&pastable examples), or use one of the wrapper libraries that exist (if you can find one that's compatible with your licensing needs).

Comment: Do we can use hook for change event download file?

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking. What are you trying to do?