# how disable file download from website using vb.net?

Tags: vb.net

i need help. how to disable file download from web browser?
i want create the web browser just for browsing and i using vb.net. i can't find the answer when i search on internet. i just find the script like this.

> `Private Sub WebBrowser1_File Download(sender As Object, e As Event) Handles`
>
> > `WebBrowser1.File Download`
> >
> > > `<-- ? -->`
>
> `End Sub`

QUESTION:
how using this?

thanks

Comment: Take a look at: http://stackoverflow.com/a/486756/2655508

Answer (score 0):

Set `WebBrowser1.AllowNavigation = False` in the FileDownload event

Hope this help you

Comment: sory, but this code make me can not open other page?any other solution?